# Ruby on Rails 3 : Playing with views

Tags: ruby, view

I am sorry for my bad english. I just try to description my question. :)
I have an application layout that have a yield for display post in body. I have another yield :footerpost3 for display title of recent post on the footer.

When I in localhost:3000, the yield :footerpost3 display a recent of title correctly. but when i am click a post link, which is the url is localhost:3000/posts/3, the yield :footerpost3 display nothing.

Here is my code:
app/views/layout/application.html.erb

```
<!-- begin footer comment widget -->
  <div class="footer_list widget_recent_comments">
    <div class="title"><h5>Artikel Terkini</h5></div>
      <%= yield :footerpost3 %>             
    </div>
<!-- end footer comment widget -->
```

app/views/store/index.html.erb

```
<% content_for :footerpost3 do %>
    <% @postsMain.each do |dopostAll| %>
        <div class="entry">
            <ul>
                <li class="recentcomments"><%= link_to dopostAll.title, dopostAll %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>                          
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

i hope my question is easy to understand.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your root url is `stores#index` .
You must be initializing `@postsMain` in the `stores#index` action and generating the content_for `footerpost3` in `stores/index.html.erb`.

When you click on a post, you will be taken to `posts#show page`. So you have to initialize `@postsMain` even in `posts#show` action and generate the content for `footerpost3` even in `posts/show.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there in your question.  You are defining the "content for" footerpost3 in that block, which exists in `index.html.erb`.  When you're on `/posts/3`, `index.html.erb` is not rendered, but rather `show.html.erb` is.

To solve this, you'd need to add the content in the `show.html.erb` template as well.

You could solve this in multiple ways.  Using nested layouts would be one.  For example, you might create a posts layout at `app/views/layout/posts.html.erb`, like so:

```
<% content_for :footerpost3 do %>
    <% @postsMain.each do |dopostAll| %>
        <div class="entry">
            <ul>
                <li class="recentcomments"><%= link_to dopostAll.title, dopostAll %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>                          
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= render :file => 'layouts/application' %>
```

In this way, all the views of your PostsController would use this layout, which simply adds your footer content, then renders the application_layout.

Comment: so i must insert a 
<%= render :file => 'layouts/application' %> 
code in every another views?
there is no simple ways? like application helper? honestly, i don't understand the application helper :)

Comment: Not every view.  This example shows how you might do it with a layout.  All your posts views (index, show, new, edit) would automatically be rendered in this layout.  So you'd only put this in one place.   The trick is that you'd have to ensure `@postsMain` was defined in all the views that render inside this layout, or they'd break.